# Report new incoming call to CallKit using SinchRTC - iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, sinch, callkit

I am using Sinch to manage calls in my app, but I can't figure out how to report the incoming call to CallKit, as required by iOS 13. I went through some of their documentation listed [here](https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-ios-cloud-push-notifications-callkit), but that's not working either. Also, the documentation states that you should report it as:

```
    - (void)managedPush:(id<SINManagedPush>)managedPush
    didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload
                              forType:(NSString *)pushType {

  id<SINNotificationResult> notification = [SINManagedPush queryPushNotificationPayload:payload];

  if ([notification isValid] && [notification isCall]) {
    NSUUID *callId = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:notification.callResult.callId];

    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:notification.callResult.remoteUserId];

    [self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:callId
                                          update:callUpdate
                                          completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                            if (error) {
                                              // Hangup call
                                            }
                                          }];
  }
}
```

When I try to implement this, I get the error that SINManagedPush doesn't contain any method such as queryPushNotificationPayload:payload, even though I'm using the latest version of Sinch, so as a workaround I found that SINPushHelper contains these properties/methods, so I'm using that. I am new in Swift and iOS environment in general, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can follow our SinchCallKit or SinchVideoCallKit sample apps, they are available inside the Samples folder on our IOS SDK.
https://download.sinch.com/ios/4.2.5/Sinch-iOS-4.2.5-a5beacdb.tar.bz2

Sinch Voice & Video Team

Comment: Those examples do not explain how to handle this.